# How to send argument dynamically to Rserve in R using rserve-js from node js?

Tags: r, node.js, rserve

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('express-session');

let Rserve = require("rserve-js");


var disease="fever";
    var dataz="cough";
enter code here
let client = Rserve.connect("localhost", 6311, function() {
console.log("Connected to Rserve.");

client.eval("datas<-read.csv('~/Desktop/data.csv')", function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("table is loaded.");

    client.eval("data<-datas[,c(2,3)]", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }


    });

    client.eval("print(data)", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }


    });


    // client.assign("x", disease);
    // client.assign("y", dataz);

    // client.eval("print(x)");

    client.eval("result<-subset(data,Sym1=='fever' | Sym1=='sweating')", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }


    });
    client.eval("da<-summary(result)", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

    });
     client.eval("print(da)", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        //console.log(response.value); // shows dimension of iris table
    });
      var result= client.eval("summary(result)", function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        //console.log(response); // shows dimension of iris table
    });
       console.log(result);
});
});


module.exports = router;
```

I am sending

```
Sym1=='fever' 
Sym1=='sweating'
```

as static data  for evaluation but I want it to be dynamic so that each time `Sym1` can be different, is there any way to assign a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very neat but you can always build the subset expression in js, like so:

```
var symptoms = ['sweating', 'fever'];
var subsetExpr = symptoms
  .map(function(symptom){ return 'Sym1==' + symptom; })
  .join(' | ');
client.eval("result<-subset(data,"+ subsetExpr +")"
```